# errors with a file tokenizer

Tags: java, tokenize

So I wrote this program to tokenize a file with code in it and separate each identifier, keyword, number, and symbol into a number token. The problem I am having is that while it will assign the first word in the each line the right token. every token in the line after is considered an identifier. Here is my tokenizer function where i believe the problem is:

```
    public class cmmLex {

    public static boolean isLetter(char b){        
        char[] letters_ = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D',
            'E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','_'};
        for (int i = 0; i < letters_.length; i++) {
            if(b == letters_[i])
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isNumber(char b){        
        char[] numbers = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if(b == numbers[i])
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isKeyword(StringBuffer str){
        String[] keywords = {"int", "double", "if", "while","return","void","else"};
        for (int i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
            if (keywords[i].equals(str.toString()))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isSymbol(char a){
        char[] symbols = {'+','-','*','/','<','>','!','=',',','.','(',')','[',']','{','}'};
        for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
            if(a == symbols[i])
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void lexMe(StringBuffer string)
    {   

        if(isKeyword(string)){
            switch(string.toString()){
                case "double":
                    System.out.print("0 ");
                    break;
                case "else":
                    System.out.print("1 ");
                    break;
                case "if":
                    System.out.print("2 ");
                    break;
                case "int":
                    System.out.print("3 ");
                    break;
                case "return":
                    System.out.print("4 ");
                    break;
                case "void":
                    System.out.print("5 ");
                    break;
                case "while":
                    System.out.print("6 ");
                    break;
            }  
        }else{
            System.out.print("27 ");
        }
    }


    public static void tokenize(String line){
        StringBuffer consumed = new StringBuffer();
        outerloop:
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            char ch = line.charAt(i);
            if(isLetter(ch) && consumed.length() == 0){
                consumed.append(line.charAt(i));
                for (int j = i+1; j < line.length(); j++) {
                    ch = line.charAt(j);
                    if(isLetter(ch) || isNumber(ch)){
                        consumed.append(ch);
                    }else{
                        //call lexme to tokenize string

                        lexMe(consumed);

                        //consumed.setLength(0);
                        i = j;
                    }

                }
            }else if(isNumber(ch) && consumed.length() == 0){
                consumed.append(line.charAt(i) );
                for (int j = i+1; j < line.length(); j++) {
                    ch = line.charAt(j);
                    if(isNumber(ch) || line.charAt(j) == '.'){
                        consumed.append(ch);
                    }else{
                        System.out.print("28 ");
                        i = j;
                    }
                }
            }else if (isSymbol(ch)){
                switch(ch){
                    case '+':
                        System.out.print("7 ");
                        break;
                    case '-':
                        System.out.print("8 ");
                        break;
                    case '*':
                        if(line.charAt(i-1) == '/'){
                            break outerloop;
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("9 ");
                        }                       
                        break;
                    case '/':
                        if(line.charAt(i+1) == '/')
                            break outerloop;
                        else if((ch = line.charAt(i+1)) == '*'){
                            consumed.append(ch);
                            for (int j = i; j < line.length(); j++) {
                                ch = line.charAt(j);
                                if(ch == '*'){
                                    if(ch == '/'){
                                        break outerloop;
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    consumed.append(ch);
                                }        

                            }
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("10 ");

                        } 
                        break;
                    case '<':
                        if(line.charAt(i+1) == '='){
                            System.out.print("12 ");
                            break;
                        }
                        System.out.print("11 ");
                        break;                 
                    case '>':
                        if(line.charAt(i+1) == '='){
                            System.out.print("14 ");
                            break;
                        }
                        System.out.print("13 ");
                        break;
                    case '!':
                        if(line.charAt(i+1) == '='){
                            System.out.print("16 ");
                            break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case '=':
                        System.out.print("15 ");
                        break;
                    case ';':
                        System.out.print("18 ");
                        break;
                    case ',':
                        System.out.print("19 ");
                        break;
                    case '.':
                        System.out.print("20 ");
                        break;
                    case '(':
                        System.out.print("21 ");
                        break;
                    case ')':
                        System.out.print("22 ");
                        break;
                    case '[':
                        System.out.print("23 ");
                        break;
                    case ']':
                        System.out.print("24 ");
                        break;
                    case '{':
                        System.out.print("25 ");
                        break;
                    case '}':
                        System.out.print("26 ");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File file = new File("src\\testCode.txt");
        String testCode;

        try {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                tokenize(line);
            }
            scanner.close();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        }

    }
}
```

Also another problem I am having is I cannot correct ignore comment blocks. I've tried to set a comment block Boolean flag when i consume "/*" and break out the loop, with the flag still set i want to scan through the rest of the lines until i see "*/" and then set the flag to false. However this did not work. Any ideas?

Here is the first line of my file:

> int fact(int x) {

It is supposed to print out this line:

> 3 27 21 3 27 22 25

and this how it currently comes out:

> 3 27 27 27 27 27

maybe i am not handling white spaces correctly?

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger? You should step through the first few lines of your input file and see why it is making the decisions it is making. That is much easier than staring at a block of code not having any idea what's going wrong.

Comment: Can you restate what the first problem was? I read it multiple times, but couldn't figure out what the issue was.

Comment: Tim: I am currently going that but i had had no success which is why i came here. @preston: My problem is after the first word in the line is tokenized correctly, the rest of the line is incorrectly tokenized.

Comment: That's a lot of code to look at w/o running--and I don't see anywhere in there where it can print `"27"` anyway. Have you considered providing *useful* debugging output rather than a string of numbers? We invented things like enums, strings-containing-letters, etc. for a reason! Also, consider some minor refactoring.

Comment: @DaveNewton I added the whole program now. As for useful output to help me what would you suggest?

Comment: @Thomas Wait, I said there was too much code, so you added more? In any case, it looks like it's not getting past your identifier token, so check the interaction between that and where it's supposed to start up again with the paren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in your loops in tokenize(). Here is the corrected version of your code :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class cmmLex {

    public static boolean isLetter(char b){        
        char[] letters_ = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D',
            'E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','_'};
        for (int i = 0; i < letters_.length; i++) {
            if(b == letters_[i])
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isNumber(char b){        
        char[] numbers = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if(b == numbers[i])
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isKeyword(StringBuffer str){
        String[] keywords = {"int", "double", "if", "while","return","void","else"};
        for (int i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
            if (keywords[i].equals(str.toString()))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isSymbol(char a){
        char[] symbols = {'+','-','*','/','<','>','!','=',',','.','(',')','[',']','{','}'};
        for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
            if(a == symbols[i])
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void lexMe(StringBuffer string)
    {   

        if(isKeyword(string)){
            switch(string.toString()){
                case "double":
                    System.out.print("0 ");
                    break;
                case "else":
                    System.out.print("1 ");
                    break;
                case "if":
                    System.out.print("2 ");
                    break;
                case "int":
                    System.out.print("3 ");
                    break;
                case "return":
                    System.out.print("4 ");
                    break;
                case "void":
                    System.out.print("5 ");
                    break;
                case "while":
                    System.out.print("6 ");
                    break;
            }  
        }else{
            System.out.print("27 ");
        }
    }


    public static void tokenize(String line){
        StringBuffer consumed = new StringBuffer();
        outerloop:
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            char ch = line.charAt(i);
            if(isLetter(ch) && consumed.length() == 0){
                consumed.append(line.charAt(i));
                for (int j = i+1; j < line.length(); j++) {
                    ch = line.charAt(j);
                    if(isLetter(ch) || isNumber(ch)){
                        consumed.append(ch);
                    }else{
                        //call lexme to tokenize string

                        lexMe(consumed);

                        consumed.setLength(0);
                        i = j - 1;
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }else if(isNumber(ch) && consumed.length() == 0){
                consumed.append(line.charAt(i) );
                for (int j = i+1; j < line.length(); j++) {
                    ch = line.charAt(j);
                    if(isNumber(ch) || line.charAt(j) == '.'){
                        consumed.append(ch);
                    }else{
                        System.out.print("28 ");
                        consumed.setLength(0);
                        i = j - 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }else if (isSymbol(ch)){
                switch(ch){
                    case '+':
                        System.out.print("7 ");
                        break;
                    case '-':
                        System.out.print("8 ");
                        break;
                    case '*':
                        if(line.charAt(i-1) == '/'){
                            break outerloop;
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("9 ");
                        }                       
                        break;
                    case '/':
                        if(line.charAt(i+1) == '/')
                            break outerloop;
                        else if((ch = line.charAt(i+1)) == '*'){
                            consumed.append(ch);
                            for (int j = i; j < line.length(); j++) {
                                ch = line.charAt(j);
                                if(ch == '*'){
                                    if(ch == '/'){
                                        break outerloop;
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    consumed.append(ch);
                                }        

                            }
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("10 ");

                        } 
                        break;
                    case '<':
                        if(line.charAt(i+1) == '='){
                            System.out.print("12 ");
                            break;
                        }
                        System.out.print("11 ");
                        break;                 
                    case '>':
                        if(line.charAt(i+1) == '='){
                            System.out.print("14 ");
                            break;
                        }
                        System.out.print("13 ");
                        break;
                    case '!':
                        if(line.charAt(i+1) == '='){
                            System.out.print("16 ");
                            break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case '=':
                        System.out.print("15 ");
                        break;
                    case ';':
                        System.out.print("18 ");
                        break;
                    case ',':
                        System.out.print("19 ");
                        break;
                    case '.':
                        System.out.print("20 ");
                        break;
                    case '(':
                        System.out.print("21 ");
                        break;
                    case ')':
                        System.out.print("22 ");
                        break;
                    case '[':
                        System.out.print("23 ");
                        break;
                    case ']':
                        System.out.print("24 ");
                        break;
                    case '{':
                        System.out.print("25 ");
                        break;
                    case '}':
                        System.out.print("26 ");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File file = new File("src\\testCode.txt");
        String testCode;

        try {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                tokenize(line);
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, while it still has some issues this is a lot better then what my output was giving me.

Answer (score 1):

Your `lexMe` method's switch is checking a string that's collecting a bit more than it should once you've gone past the first word.

Use a debugger to see it, or put a debug print of that value, and you'll see the problem.

That issue appears to be because the line

```
  consumed.setLength(0);
```

was commented out in your posted code.

With that put back in, there are still issues, as immediately after handling the "fact" string, it contines a for loop that is inside a condition based on the check `if(isLetter(ch) && consumed.length() == 0)` when it really should be rechecking that condition.

I'd recommend use of a debugger to understand what your code is currently doing and then some major refactoring.

**Note**

I've now looked at the other answer, which picks up and (I assume without actually running) corrects these issue by adding a break.

But I'd strongly advise rethinking the whole thing, as nesting loops and conditionals and using `break` makes for really confusing code.

Answer (score 0):

Handwritten lexical analyzers are always a pain to write and debug. May I suggest that you use a higher level tool to do this, eg: JLex, or JFlex. This will save you a lot of pain.